# Python/Pandas - How to slice a list up to the first 5 values when some lists might have less than 5 values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following use case where I have a pandas DataFrame with a column of Series/lists. All of the Series/lists vary in length, but I want to take up to the first 5 elements of this list and set them to their own column.

First, I tried just setting a new column up with a slice of the Series/list (e.g. df.full_column.tolist()[:5]), but I get an error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

So I basically have two problems:

1. First getting the list of up to 5 from the original column. For further clarification, if there is only 4 in the list, then I want all 4.
2. Taking this list and creating columns off of all of them. Something like value_0, value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, where if the list didn't have the 4th or 5th, it will set to NaN

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @ScottBoston in jpp's answer below, he captures the example perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.values.tolist()` and pass this to `pd.DataFrame`. The solution will work for any max length of list within your list of lists.

You can, if you wish, drop unwanted columns afterwords via [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

lst = [[[1]],
       [[1, 2]],
       [[1, 2, 3]],
       [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]],
       [[1, 2, 3, 4]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df['Col'] = 5

#                  0  Col
# 0              [1]    5
# 1           [1, 2]    5
# 2        [1, 2, 3]    5
# 3  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    5
# 4     [1, 2, 3, 4]    5
```

**Solution**

```
df2 = df.drop(0, 1).join(pd.DataFrame(df[0].values.tolist()))

#    Col  0    1    2    3    4
# 0    5  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 1    5  1  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 2    5  1  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
# 3    5  1  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
# 4    5  1  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN
```

**Explanation**

- `pd.DataFrame` accepts a list of lists with variable length as an input.
- `df[0].values.tolist()` returns the jagged list of lists via the numpy representation of the series.
- `join` joins on index by default.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use str accessor and indexing with `assign`:

```
df.assign(**pd.DataFrame(df[0].str[:5].tolist()).add_prefix('value_'))
```

Output:

```
                                                   0  value_0  value_1  value_2  value_3  value_4
0                     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]        0        1        2        3        4
1  [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, ...      100      101      102      103      104
2  [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 100...     1000     1001     1002     1003     1004
```

Comment: Is `str` accessor vectorised? Reason I ask is [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) says it is, but [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/strings.py#L1068-L1084) suggests it's a loopy `lambda`.

Comment: @jpp I think you are right I have seen map out perform .str methods.